# CpuFreq on Android

Tags: android, api, cpu

I was trying to find the cycles per second for an Android device and stumbled upon this API class: http://static.meizu.com/m9sdk/reference/android/os/CPUfreq.html

Has anyone used this before? What do read and save methods do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> stumbled upon this API class

There is no CpuFreq in the Android SDK, and there does not appear to be such a class in the current Android source code.

> Has anyone used this before?

Hopefully not, except perhaps in a firmware app.

Answer (score 0):

You can try read this file /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[x]/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq (x starts from 0 to the total core number - 1) to get each core's current cpu frequency.

Answer (score 0):

If its cycles per second that you want, you can easily modify `Perf` to give you this statistic. `perf stat` by default gives you statistics collected over one long time period. However, its quite simple to modify `perf` to give you statistics over smaller intervals.

To include `perf` into your android source, you should

`git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/linux-tools-perf/` in your `external` folder